# Getting a C++ program to write to a file

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, g++

For creating a programming question for a competition, I need about 49999 unique, random numbers. I have written a C++ program to generate the numbers, but I run into a problem when actually *copying* the numbers from the terminal screen because only around ~6700 numbers are displayed in the terminal's screen.

So is there a way I can get the C++ program to automatically write the random numbers to a file? Or is it possible to write a shell script which can take the C++ output to do the same? I'm using g++ on ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)?

Comment: There will be approximately a billion C++ examples of how to output info to a text file. Give one of those a try and if you cannot make it work, then post the issue.

Comment: okay the downvotes are depressing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying you're printing numbers to stdout and they're going off the screen. Since you're using C++ you can replace cout in your output instructions with an ofstream (output file stream) like so:

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
    ofstream outFile("myNums.txt");
    // ...
    outFile << myNum;
```

An easier way if you already have the program done is to just redirect the output. This means when you run your program add > myNums.txt to the end. So for instance:

```
./myProg > myNums.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers are simply printing to the terminal window now:

```
program > file
```

Where `program` is the name of your program -- or whatever command and arguments you are using to run it now -- and `file` is the name you want to give to the file you create.

For more information on this particular solution, see:

> [Redirection (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)

For more information on how the interactive command interpreter, `bash`, can help you, see:

> [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Bash is the most commonly used shell program on Linux and many other Unix and Unix-like operating systems today, but almost every other Unix shell since the beginning of time -- the midnight separating December 31, 1969 from January 1, 1970 -- has used the same program standard input and output -- and error -- syntax.